UIApplication.shared.open Doesn't work sometimes
I'm running into an issue where my UIApplication.shared.open doesn't work. I'm running an app that start Picture in Picture mode whenever you minimize it. The UIApplication.shared.open works fine when the app is fully in the foreground but when I minimize the UIApplication.shared.open fails.
@objc func turnPage() {
        // Your code here
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let url = URL(string: "forscore://action?type=nextpage")
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!) { (result) in
            if result{
                print("turned page")
            }
        }
        print("This code runs every 5 seconds")
    }
}

The code prints turned page whenever the app is in the foreground. but whenever I go to the background it stops working and doesn't print turned page
